# Used an authlistener firebase but still does not work to delete user

Tags: kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I have followed this tutorial [Tutorial by Alex mamo](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) and got it finnished. When i now check if a user exist and i have a clean build of my emulator it works but if i run it on an already hot build of my emulator the firebase database still answers me with a user id why is this? this is my code...

AuthListener:

```
override fun getFirebaseAuthState() = callbackFlow<Boolean>{
    val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        println("Current user:" + auth.currentUser)
        trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.checkIfUserExists()?.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    awaitClose {
       auth.checkIfUserExists()?.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: IAuthRepository) : ViewModel() {  

    private val _event : MutableStateFlow<AuthEvent> = MutableStateFlow(AuthEvent.notBeingUsed)
    val event : StateFlow<AuthEvent> = _event

    fun checkIfUserExists() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getFirebaseAuthState().collectLatest{task ->
            println("Task2:" + task)
            if(task){
                _event.value = AuthEvent.Failure("User is not logged in")
            }else{
                _event.value = AuthEvent.Success
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UI:

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel : SplashViewModel = hiltViewModel()){
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val overshootInterpolator = remember {
            OvershootInterpolator(2f)
        }

        val scale = remember {
            Animatable(0f)
        }
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
            scale.animateTo(
                targetValue = 1f,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 500,
                    easing = {
                        overshootInterpolator.getInterpolation(it)
                    }
                )
            )
            delay(Constants.SPLASH_SCREEN_DURATION)
            viewModel.checkIfUserExists()
            viewModel.event.collect{
                println("Task it: " + it)
                when(it){
                    is AuthEvent.Success -> {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(PaperSellerScreens.CustomerListScreen.name)
                    }
                    is AuthEvent.Failure ->{
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(PaperSellerScreens.LoginScreen.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val painterIcon = painterResource(R.drawable.logo_size_invert)
        val painterBackground = painterResource(id = R.drawable.paper_seller_background)
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            Image(painter = painterBackground, contentDescription = "SplashScreen",contentScale = ContentScale.Crop, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
            Image(painterIcon, "Icon Image", modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 200.dp)
                .scale(scale.value)
                .align(
                    Alignment.Center
                )
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)))

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexMamo: since you wrote the tutorial, you're probably best equipped to answer. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "if I run it on an already hot build of my emulator the firebase database still answers me with a user id"?

Comment: if i wipe that data of the emulator it notices that there is no users left when i have deleted the user. When i rerun the app on an emulator that i have not wiped the data on it still gives me a user eaven if i have deleted the user so it still logs me in